# Getting error when accessing Microsoft Teams channel messages via Microsoft Graph API: Proxy_InternalServerError

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

When getting Teams channel messages via delegated permissions (user is a member of the team):

https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{team_id}/channels/{channel_id}/messages/

Getting error:

```
{
  "error": {
  "code": "Proxy_InternalServerError",
  "message": "Failure in forwarding request.",
  "innerError": {
    "request-id": "511b812c-df43-402b-b9dd-34ca1c1bd397",
    "date": "2019-02-01T14:22:50"
  }
}
```

Tested with Graph Explorer and code.

Does it work for anybody?

Comment: Retried recently again, new error response:

{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "Bad Request",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "d8a474d7-08c3-46ea-87c0-f31e88363303",
            "date": "2019-04-07T06:01:38"
        }
    }
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your channel id. probably colon is missing in the Channel ID or formation is not correct. It should be in the below format
- 20:d0bba23c2fc8413991125a54a67dd13e@thread.skype

Comment: Should be correct, because this request works: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{id}/channels/{id}/

Comment: But after I took id with "*@thread.skype" - messages endpoint works. Thanks!